# Azure Functions and Google API with Google OAuth2 (node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-api, azure-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to access a Google spreadsheet from within Azure Functions, using Oauth2 and Node.js.
I'm able to use Node.js with Token management on the filesystem, running on-premise. But Azure Functions should be able to handle Google Authentication from within Azure Functions (I've entered client-id, secrets, ticket Google Auth...), but how do I write a node.js which lets Azure Functions handle the authentication? Can I refer to Tokens with some Azure variable? Does anyone have a working example?
Thank you

Comment: How do you intend to be able to authorize consent with Node.js from an azure function.  How are you going to show the consent screen?

Comment: I thought I need to do that once with browser, and Azure Functions would thenn be taking care of the refresh token mechanism. But I found no working examples with Google Auth implemntation, so I'm not sure I got it right.

Comment: maybe i understand wrongly , you are trying to use node.js to logon Google auth service, and why Azure Functions involved ?

Comment: @Mara yes you can do that once with a browser but how are you going to get to the browser from an azure function?

Comment: I thought I would be able to authenticate with Google Account and that would authorize the Azure Function to access to Google Scopes (Sheets) using my credentials. I guess I got something wrong there, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a start, you may refer to [quick start Google Sheet APIv4 - node.js](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) to under how it works, and follow the prerequisites.

after you complete and understand this is by nature **server-side web apps**, you can start thinking putting these in server-less functions (e.g Azure Functions).